# GDB-python register_changed event handler

Tags: python, gdb, embedded, gdb-python

I am creating a GDB TUI python extension for embedded debugging. The python script is being run by the GDB. Trying to create a handler for register_changed event in GDB according to the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html) like so:

```
def reg_changed_handler(event):
    print('register changed' + str(event.regnum))

gdb.events.register_changed.connect(reg_changed_handler)
```

I can't get working this very specific event handler. Other events are implemented in the very same way and are working fine. Is there something I am missing?
I am running gdb 12.1-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Python 3.10.6

I don't clearly understand when the event occurs.
From the documentation: *Emits gdb.RegisterChangedEvent which indicates that a register in the inferior has been modified by the GDB user.*

Does it mean, that the event occurs only when I specifically change a register (in assembly code)? Or it occurs every time, any register is changed (after compilation to assembly)

I tried evoking the event by modifying specific registers in assembly on my embedded dev board, but without success.

Comment: `modified by the GDB user` means if you manually change a register inside gdb.

Comment: Thx, it works now when I change the register value in GDB using `set` command. I expected the event handler to give me an interrupt every time any register is changed (not by user)